# loop write.csv dataframes

Tags: r, loops, csv

R newbie here: I have seen multiple posts about looping write csv, but none where it inputs dataframes (not lists of dataframes) and loops to write a csv. I would like to loop through all dataframes, and create one csv per dataframe matching the dataframe name.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(1:10, 6, replace = TRUE)
  , var2 = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 6, replace = TRUE)
  , theday = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(1:10, 6, replace = TRUE)
  , var2 = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 6, replace = TRUE)
  , theday = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
)
```

I have a character list with the names of the dataframes, but the data itself lives in the dataframes.

```
temp <- list("df1", "df2")
```

Output should have the data within a csv labeled 'df1.csv' and df2.csv
I would think it would be something like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)) write.csv(temp[i])
```

But this instead writes to the console and does perform write csv. Ideas?!

Comment: 1. You should use `get`. 2. You need to pass a file name to `write.csv`.

Comment: And of course these data.frames should probably be in a `list`, because you are looping over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Roland comment, you should loop over your list (with `lapply` for example) and use `get` and `write.csv`:

```
lapply(temp, function(u) write.csv(get(u), file=u))
```

To store your `data.frame` in a list you can do:

```
Filter(function(u) class(get(u))=='data.frame', ls())
```

Comment: I'm trying to get around having to write out every dataframe to list conversion. I have 35 data frames that I am trying to export. Is there a way to go directly from data frame to csv without converting to a list?

Comment: I edited my post. Again this is very bad to put your data.frame in the global environment and fetch them afterwards. It is far better to store them in a list directly (`temp`). Besides, I do not know if your data.frames have some pattern in their name, eg `df1`, `df2`, ...,`dfXX` : you could use is as `pattern` argument in `ls`.